# How is topic-prominence different than OSV word order?

Tags: syntax, word-order, topic-comment

I have read that "most East-Asian languages" are topic-prominent languages, which means putting the topic (object) first before the subject, and the verb last, but they never say explicitly that this is OSV structure. However, the [Wikipedia word order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_order) page says OSV languages are by far the rarest. I have read that in Chinese topic-first-ness is much more common for native speakers, and is the preferred way of speaking. So who/what is incorrect here? Wikipedia is saying OSV is the rarest, yet other pages are saying topic-firstness (in Chinese and others) is the most common form, and I am reading this as OSV. So I am confused.

- How is topic-prominence different than OSV word order?
- If they are the same, then is Wikipedia wrong? How popular then is OSV or topic-prominence?

Comment: You’ve based this question on a false premise: topic isn’t the same as object, so topic-prominence **doesn’t** mean putting the object first. The topic _can_ be the object, but it can also be the subject or any other constituent, including the subject (at least in theory – in practice, some are very rarely topicalised, like main verbs).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't think verb topicalization is that rare. It's fairly common in classical Greek, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A topic-prominent language is one that structures sentences so at to make most-obvious what the discourse topic is, and what comment is made about that topic. This can be done in various ways, especially by marking the topic with some topic-indicating morpheme – for example, -wa in Japanese marks the topic. An alternative, in this typology, is subject-prominence, where the syntax "focuses" on signalling the subject of the sentence. Anything can be a topic, or a subject. Depending on your framework, a sentence might have both a subject and a topic in a language.

"OSV" simply means that the usual, "unmarked" word order in a sentence is O, S, V, and discourse topicality is orthogonal (the object might be the topic, or the the subject, or the verb). However, word order could be a device for signalling topicality, so a language with at least possible OSV order could use that order as a device for marking topic (topic-marking inflection isn't the sole defining means of making a topic prominent).

Statistically-speaking, more languages are subject-prominent than are topic-prominent, and OSV is a rarer order of the six possible orders (SVO, SOV and VSO are the most common orders, VSO is in third place in that set).

Answer (score 6):

To put it simply, "topic" and "object" are not the same. The topic can have any syntactic role in the sentence (subject, object, main verb, etc): it's whichever element is most relevant to the discourse.